# How to work out total length of presenter links and length of footage as a whole per link?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, estimation

This is the video I've been using from YouTube for the question I set myself:

A television show is $24$ minutes and $26$ seconds long, with $6$ presenter links and $6$ different sequences of footage. [Original show here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyQ1xrFuMFQ) . How long in total, including the opening intro is each piece of footage for the $24$ minute and $26$ second show?

I tried:

$\frac{24.43}{2} = 12.22$

Each part (before commercial break) is $12$ min $13$ s long

I then tried:

$\frac{12.22}{3} = 4.07$

Each presenter link, including footage is $4$ minutes $7$ seconds long ($\frac{7}{60} = 0.12$).

The opening titles are $27$ seconds long ($0.63 - 0.18$, i.e. $38$ seconds - $27$ seconds, but $\frac{38}{60}$ and $\frac{11}{60}$ to get it as $0.63$ and $0.18$)

I haven't quite worked out how to get to the result of working out the length of each individual presenter link, and each clip (i.e. clips as a whole, not individual clips themselves) to get to fit the show's length.

I would appreciate it if anyone could check my math is right, sometimes I get these things wrong.

This may be useful things to know for if I do videos/YouTube in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming at here. If you have two video clips that are in total 10 minutes, it doesn't mean that each is exactly 5 minutes long. It just states that their sum is something. But if you divide the length like that, you get the **average** length. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want the exact lengths of all the clips, you have to sit through the video and mark down every starting and ending time.